# xml_grep exclude element that contains an element

Tags: xml

I'm trying to remove all elements from an XML file that contain a certain other element.  Here's a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do.  Suppose I have the XML file

```
<RootEl>
   <A>
      <B/>
   </A>
   <A>
      <C/>
   </A>
 </RootEl>
```

If I wanted to keep all and only the A's that DO contain B's, I could use this command line:

```
xml_grep -root A -cond B < TheFile.xml
```

But if I want to do the reverse--keep only the A's that do NOT contain B's, I'm at a loss.  A command similar to the above, namely

```
xml_grep -root A -exclude B < TheFile.xml
```

gives me

```
<RootEl>
   <A>

   </A>
   <A>
      <C/>
   </A>
 </RootEl>
```

whereas what I want is

```
<RootEl>
   <A>
      <C/>
   </A>
 </RootEl>
```

I get the same undesired answer if I use

```
xml_grep -root A -exclude A/B < TheFile.xml
```

or

```
xml_grep -exclude A/B < TheFile.xml
```

I could figure out how to do this in Python, and I suppose it's possible in xslt.  But I was hoping for a way to do this in xml_grep.

BTW, I'm sure someone will ask why I don't just tell it I want the As that contain Cs.  The problem is that there are 20 or so things an A can contain besides B or C, so I'd have to specify an A that contains a C or a D or...or a Z.  Which is a whole lot more work than specifying the one kind of A I don't want.

The question [Delete XML node containing certain element](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72157/delete-xml-node-containing-certain-element) is asking basically the same question, but there are no answers there using xml_grep.  I'm hoping someone can suggest such an answer, since xml_grep seems reasonably popular and built for purposes like this...almost.

Comment: I think I can do this with `xmlstarlet`. Do you need to use `xml_grep`?

Comment: I hadn't heard of xmlstarlet before; from the documentation, it looks like it might work.  I'm installing it now, I'll let you know how it works.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yeap, it works!  For the record, this is the command line:  `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "RootEl" -c "A[not(./B)]"`     I am now sold on xmlstarlet!

Comment: I chose Kusalananda's offered answer, although roaima actually suggested that approach in above (but as a comment, not an "answer").  Thanks to both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//A[not(B)]' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootEl>
  <A>
    <B/>
  </A>
</RootEl>
```

The XPATH expression `//A[not(B)]` would select all `A` nodes in the document that does not contain a `B` node as a child node.  These selected nodes are deleted.

The expression could also be written as `//A[not(child::B)]` which would be a bit more explicit.